# How can i use nodejs webrtc in an symfony app?

Tags: node.js, symfony, socket.io, webrtc

I have a web site developped with symfony and I want to add a live video chat feature.
I've read that the best way to do this , it's to use webrtc, socket.io on nodejs.
So i create a little projet beside and i follow this recommandation:
https://dev.to/jeffersonxavier/webrtc-a-simple-video-chat-with-javascript-1686
It works!

Now when I want to integrate it with my website, i ran  the symfony app on 8000 and i run the node server on 3000.

So i replaced

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When i run the page i have the following error:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NSMihfq.

I don't understand why socket.io try to reconnect on the port 8000 of the app.

how can i get the server node to work in my php page ?
Or what is the best way to do what i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a library called PeerJS to utilize Webrtc in my projects (Video/Audio/Chat).
You should look into how Webrtc works in the real world, the basic idea is. You need a server called a stun server to act as a middle man to set up the peer to peer talking.
After the setup is done the peers will talk to each other.

I highly suggest you use PeerJs, I was able to set up my workflow in about 2 hours due to the high-level nature of the api.
[Peer Js](https://peerjs.com/)

Comment: sorry to answer you so late but I needed to try peerjs before giving you an answer .So Thank you so much alphabin, it was exaclty what i was looking for. I integrate it into my website and it works like a charm. Thx